# Export tf.Keras 2.2 model to tflite with Static Tensors for accelerating using delegates

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, coreml, tensorflow-lite

I am exporting tf.Keras 2.2 model using default converter, and everything works good, except it can't use CoreML/GPU accelerator. The reason is "Attempting to use a delegate that only supports static-sized tensors with a graph that has dynamic-sized tensors." It is common problem, even in NNDelegate it described. But there is no info in the docs how to solve this.

Comment: Make sure your model does not compute the sizes of tensors based on the size of other tensors (such as the input). For example, you cannot do a reshape of the data to fit it to an arbitrary tensor size. The shape must be hardcoded into the model.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans I played a lot with NN, and now I have input_shape and batch_size in every node. also I am exporting NN with tf.concete_function and with input tensor description. But still tflite say that I have dynamic sized tensors. I don't understand how to describe output shape of model. May be here is a problem. I tried to google, but I don't have any useful information.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans I had an idea to assemble this NN using MPS, but I need this NN on Android as well, so I need NNAPI accelerator, which wants static tensors as well.

Comment: @OleksiiMoisieienko did you solve?  I'm facing the same issue